# Multiplying 10 times with opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier

Firstly I have V1 and V2 values very close to each other in voltage. 
(used symmetric supply of +12 V and -12V, I did not draw it to create complexity)

I subtracted one from the other with opamp U2 then eliminated DC value with capacitor.

Now I have values between -10mv ~ +10 mv and I have to multiply with 11 these values but 
last part is not doing his job. The output is the same before and after opamp U3.

What is the reason ot that?

[image]

Comment: What AC frequency?

Comment: *opamp power terminals are 12 volts.* Be precise, do you mean a single supply of +12V (so GND and + 12 V) or a symmetric supply of +12 V and -12V? C1 blocks all DC, but I'd say the signal you want to measure is also DC or at least very low in frequency. So C1 will block it as well. Using C1 would only work if the difference between V1 and V2 is an AC signal with a high enough frequency that it isn't filtered out by C1 and R8.

Comment: Check the ground connection of R9. Without ground connected, it behaves like another buffer, possible the issue you're seeing.

Comment: as you said @Bimpelrekkie and lastly I have to multiply this signal with 10. All I want is this.

Comment: Sure it is clear what you want, yet you have not responded to Andy's *What AC frequency?* and my *Using C1 would only work if the difference between V1 and V2 is an AC signal with a high enough frequency that it isn't filtered out by C1 and R8* I think that you generate a DC signal (V1 - V2) but then **block it** with C1.

Comment: What typical range of values are you expecting for V1 and V2?

Comment: Geez, I only just noticed that D1 and D2 do a huge "compression" of the currents from the NTCs (R2, R3) so even if D1 and D2 are kept at the same temperature (V1-V2) will be needlessly small. So user70: please explain why D1 and D2 are diodes and not resistors as that would make more sense in my opinion.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie to create random and equally likely outputs or bring it closer it

Comment: Both output voltages will be present so 100% likely. But why make the voltage difference smaller (by D1 and D2) and then later in the chain amplify the difference again? If D1 and D2 are replaced by resistors with the right value you can dimension the circuit such that you do not need amplification. Also, if there is a temperature difference between D1 and D2 you will get an output voltage (V1-V2) even if the NTCs are at the same temperature.

Comment: I need to use diodes, that is the reason. I can't change dioes with resistor. Please understand me

Comment: "I can't change dioes with resistor. Please understand me" - Sorry, but I don't understand, and I worked for 35 years doing this sort of stuff. Plus, temperatures simply don't change quickly; so why are you high-passing your signal? Your approach makes no sense at all. Try editing to explain what you are trying to do and justify your choice of circuit. I suspect we have a bad case of xy problem here.

Comment: -1 because you've had 6 hours to clarify what is the AC frequency of the signal you're trying to measure, and haven't responded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have misunderstood your circuit, not to mention some of your components.

First, your problem, which you have not explained. It appears that you are trying to measure the temperature difference between two points. Using a pair of thermistors is a perfectly reasonable first approach. However, using a pair of diodes to compress the signals suggests that you are trying to use a single pair of thermistors over a large temperature range. This is A Bad Idea.

Your part number can be found on page 13 of [the data sheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/29049/ntcle100.pdf), and it has a 25C resistance of 220 ohms. With a 4 volt excitation voltage and a diode drop in series, the maximum current through the thermistors will be at most about 3 mA.

Despite what you seem to think, a 1N4007 is about as bad a choice for this application as you can make. It simply is not characterized for this current level, and you should replace it with a good small-signal diode such as a 1N4148.

Let's assume you have done so. You can find a data sheet [here](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81857/1n4148.pdf) Note, for instance, that change in thermistor current from 1 mA to 2 mA will produce a voltage difference of about .04 volts. This would correspond to a temperature change from -20 to 5 C, for a sensitivity of about 1.6 microvolts per degree C. Your total circuit gain is about 22, for a sensitivity of about 35 uV per degree C. Somehow, I doubt that this is going to be useful.

Contrast this with simply tying the thermistors to ground and supplying each with its own 1k resistor. Then going from -20 to 5 C will produce a sensitivity of about 48 mV/C, or a thousand times better. Even at temperatures of 70 to 80 C gives a sensitivity of about 400 uV/C, or ten times better.

And, of course, your voltage drops across the diodes are extremely senstive to temperature effects at the diode, so unless you're careful to thermally couple them you'll have problems as well.

Now, about your high-pass filter. That makes no sense at all. When you talk about removing "the DC value", exactly what DC value are you talking about? Your temperatures are, essentially, DC in the first place. I assume you're talking about the common-mode signal, since you're obviously interested in the temperature differential. I've got news for you - that is the point of the U1/U2 circuit. It's a differential amplifier. Its output, assuming excellent resistor matching in both value and temperature drift, is exactly what you want. The idea that you are interested in temperature shifts at frequencies above the high-pass limit (about 160 Hz, as Olin has pointed out) is, well, it's pretty mind boggling. You would be much better off simply changing R6 and R7 to 68k and getting rid of U3.

As for your output, if you're getting significant signal at 2.5 - 10 MHz from an LM358, you're kidding yourself that you're seeing something valid. From the [data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158-n.pdf) the open loop gain falls to zero at 1 MHz. I suspect that you don't know how to properly ground your circuit and scope, so you're picking up RF noise in the environment.

It occurs to me that what you are trying to do is make a random noise generator, which would explain the high-pass filter. In that case, you don't want to use forward-biased diodes in the first place, and especially not 1N4007s, even though you have some on hand. You have no need to use NTCs, and you don't need a differential setup. And, as mentioned before, if you're interested in >1 MHz, LM358s are useless.

So, just exactly what ARE you trying to do?

Comment: "And, as mentioned before, if you're interested in >1 MHz, LM358s are useless.". THANKS!
I thank you all individually for your interest and I apologize if I made you angry.
I'm dealing with very low voltages, I was applying your suggestions and finally reached 90MHz frequency with a lot of noise (and it was hard to find the frequency). I reviewed your comments and I decided to use better quality and suitable opamp (with reading data sheets) for use in this project. And again thanks all.

Comment: @user70 - Without knowing what you're trying to do, let me caution you that at 90 MHz you probably can't use op amps the way you're trying to. This is will into RF territory, and among other things parasitic aspects will make it very difficult to make a differential amp.

Answer (score 4):

Your final opamp (U3A) is wired correctly for positive gain.  With the resistors you show, its gain will actually be 11, not 10, but that's not related to the problem you are observing.

So what to do?  Start debugging, obviously.

First verify the signal at the output of U2A.  From your description, it seems that is as expected.  OK, so keep going.  What about the right side of C1?  Does that make it to the positive input of U3A?  Check right at the pin.  Don't assume the connections are correct and working.  If the signal is at the positive input of U3A, what's on the negative input?  It should be the same signal.  Then check the output.

Again, this kind of diagnosing really should have been the obvious thing to do.

If everything is built as shown by the schematic, then one problem may be the frequency of the signal.  Saying that C1 "blocks DC" oversimplifies it.  C1 and R8 really work together to form a high pass filter.  In this case, the rolloff frequency is 160 Hz.  Is your signal lower frequency than that?  If so, that explains why you're not seeing it on the output, or why it is more attenuated than you expect.

If you replace R8 with 10 kΩ, for example, then the high pass rolloff frequency goes to 16 Hz.  That also puts less of a load on U2A.

All the above is assuming the LM358 is used correctly.  You didn't link to a datasheet, so I didn't look it up and check any of that.

Comment: Thanks, edited to 11 (actually I have used non-inverting then changed to inverting the "10" had left in my mind). Also debugged everywhere of this circuit with knowledgeable about the subject, checked everywhere. I'm dealing with noise actually and frequency comes from there, the oscilloscope shows the frequency of the output between 2.5 MHz - 10 MHz, still searching.